# Problems with the Google Places API AddPlaceRequest - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, google-places-api

I'm in the process of creating an application on Android Studio which allows a user to select a location on a map and add some details to that location - E.g. Select a football pitch and add some details to it such as 5 a side football match on Sunday at 12 o'clock. 
Once these details are saved that location is saved onto the map along with those details.

I've decided to use the Google Places API as it has the AddPlace feature. Instead of adding a business to the map like the API was intended for, I want to tweak it so it can add an event instead.

However, the example found here at:

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/add-place

Does not work in my application.

Here are the screenshots:

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1DWq.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated - Thank you
G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Add A Place* function of the Places API isn't a good fit for what you're trying to do. Add Place is designed to allow users to add places that don't currently exist in Google Maps' database. It sounds like what you want to do is attach some metadata to a place that has meaning only to your app.

So, you'll need some persistent server storage for this metadata. There are lots of ways to do this but you might want to look at [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) as a solution.

Also, from the screenshot, it looks like your error comes from not having defined `mGoogleApiClient` in in your app.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Will have a look into the Firebase now!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to make a connection to one of the Google APIs provided in the Google Play services library (such as Google Sign-In, Games, or Drive), you need to create an instance of GoogleApiClient ("Google API Client"). See here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client